# The use of the relative pronoun "whose" in a sentence

Tags: relative-pronouns

How is "whose" used as relative pronoun and is it possible to use it when we're specifying things?

I built up a sentence with "whose":

> I have a book **whose** story is about chaina town.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it is possible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whose?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) to use **whose** to refer to things as well as persons.

*This is the house **whose attic** is haunted.*

Answer (score 0):

I have a book whose story is about China Town.

The usage of whose in the sentence is correct grammatically. You can use whose as a relative pronoun to describe things.

In fact, whose is the possessive form of who. But, as there are no possessive forms of which and that, the whose is commonly used to refer to things as compared to the alternative "of which" which is considered rather awkward. For examples:

It's the house whose doors are painted red.

It's the house, the doors of which are painted red.

However, if you to avoid using whose, you can rephrase the sentence as follows:

I have a story book on/about China Town.